# Counting the lines of several txt files

Tags: vba, excel

I need to count the lines (records) of a several txt files and record on a excel.
Can you help me the to find the best way to do that?

I thought on a VBA macro in excel but I don't have enough skills.

Basic the procedure is:
1. open x files txt
2. record on excel in one cell the title of the file and in other cell the number os lines/records.
    for example-> txt file with 100 records and title TEST should appears:
     A1    A2
     Title 100

Comment: Seems like this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416553/function-to-count-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file

Comment: I want to select 1000 or more txt files (of one time) instead of just one.

Comment: think about loops then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Loop_Through_Text_Files_Count_Lines()
Dim fso         As Object
Dim pth         As Object
Dim strFolder   As String
Dim strFile     As String
Dim r           As Long

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show Then strFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" Else Exit Sub
End With

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.txt")

Do While strFile <> ""
    r = r + 1
    Set pth = fso.OpenTextFile(strFile, 1)
    pth.ReadAll

    Cells(r, 1).Value = strFile
    Cells(r, 2).Value = pth.Line

    strFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems great! Thank you but I can't choose txt files. Could you change the code to open all files from one folder instead of files?

Comment: The code already enables you to select the folder that has the text files ..

Comment: Ok, nice but doesn't allow me. Error debug in "Set pth = fso.OpenTextFile(strFile, 1)"